# Program to auto-update data in Excel files

Tags: microsoft-excel

Each day for work, I have to open 40-50 Excel files (the newer .xlsx format) and run the `Data Refresh` on all connections in order for them to pull in the latest numbers. As you can imagine, this takes quite a while to complete.
Is there some sort of program that I can use that will open all of these files at once and run the Data Refresh in the background so I don't have to go into each file and run it manually?

Answer (score 7):

In Excel

1. Create new document.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.
3. Double-click item **Sheet1** in top-left tool window.
4. Paste the following macro into large code window:

   ```
   Public Sub RefreshMyDocs()
       RefreshDoc "D:\Data\Sheet1.xlsx"
       RefreshDoc "D:\Data\Sheet2.xlsx"
       RefreshDoc "D:\Data\Sheet3.xlsx"
       RefreshDoc "D:\Data\Sheet4.xlsx"
       RefreshDoc "D:\Data\Sheet5.xlsx"
   End Sub

   Private Sub RefreshDoc(AbsolutePathToFile As String)
       Dim W As Workbook
       Set W = Workbooks.Open(AbsolutePathToFile)
       W.RefreshAll
       Rem W.Close   'remove Rem if you wish to close given document after refresh
   End Sub
   ```
5. Adjust the list of files found in `RefreshMyDocs`.
6. While keeping text cursor within area between `Public Sub RefreshMyDocs()` and its adjacent `End Sub`, press <kbd>F5</kbd> to run this code. (**Note:** to avoid "document is already open" error, make sure that none of listed docs is currently open – close them first.)
7. Save your document with macro.

Hints: Test with one or two files first, then add the rest. Mind specifying files with their full paths.

Answer (score 0):

If a programmatic solution will be acceptable, [Essential XlsIO](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/xlsio) can be used to auto update data in Excel files. This is completely independent of Excel.

Simple sample application with source code: [link](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/161271/ze/DataRefresh-285198080).

```
     //Step 1 : Instantiate the spreadsheet creation engine. 
ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine(); 
//Step 2 : Instantiate the excel application object. 
IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel; 

//Set the Workbook version 
application.DefaultVersion = ExcelVersion.Excel2013; 

//Open the workbook 
IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(file, ExcelOpenType.Automatic); 

//Get the 1st sheet from the workbook 
IWorksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0]; 

//Refresh all the connections in the workbook 
for (int i = 0; i < workbook.Connections.Count; i++) 
{ 
    //Refresh the table 
    //Note : Exception will occur if no valid connection 
    sheet.ListObjects[i].Refresh(); 
} 

//Save the workbook to disk. 
workbook.Save(); 

//Close the workbook. 
workbook.Close(); 
excelEngine.Dispose();
```

The source requires Visual Studio and Syncfusion Essential Studio to compile.

[Documentation link](http://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/xlsio/working-with-tables#create-a-table-from-external-connection)

The whole suite of controls is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue). Note: I work for Syncfusion.